# avoid translateX going beyond parent width - CSS

Tags: css, transform

For demo purposes imagine the following structure:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
```

the div with class="wrapper" has a fixed width of let's say 200px;
the inner div with class="box" has a 50% width of its parent.

I want to create a effect with translateX for the inner div to slide and leave when it reaches the border of the parent div.

I have this plunker which is not working. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VM4xqrA12gGhY9fbkHAm?p=preview)

How can I prevent it from going beyond its parent width?

Comment: what do you mean by `leave when it reaches the border of the parent div.`

Comment: You want the box to disappear on the right edge? Isn't it just `overflow: hidden` on the parent? Can you clarify your question if this is not the case

Comment: @Huangism yes! that's it! thank you

Comment: @Bhuwan i wanted it to slide to the right and disappear when reaching the parent border. already got an answer. thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to the parent element (`.wrapper`).

Comment: Yup! that's precisely it! Thank you for your help!